# how can we replace a character in user input?

Tags: java, string, replace, user-input

I want it for my homework I'm coding for Hawaiian language pronunciation in java. i have tried if-else statements but it doesn't work

just like if i enter "hola"
it should give me H OH L AH 
and if i write "aioo"
it should give me EYE OH OH

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Hawain {
    public static void main (String args []){
        Scanner obj=new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println ("Enter any word in hawaii language:");

        String var=obj.nextLine();
        System.out.println (var);

        if (var.equals("ai"))
            System.out.println(var.replace("ai" , "eye") );
        else if (var.equals("a")) 
            System.out.println(var.replace("a" , "ah"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add more details. What output exactly are you getting? Does the case of the words matter?

Answer (score 0):

Please use 'contains("ai")' instead 'equals("ai")

```
if (var.contains("ai")) {
  // Replace it
}
if (var.contains("a")) {
  // Replace it
}
// etc.
```

Comment: can you help me in writing my program?

Comment: my program is about hawai language that when you enter any word of hawai language it will provide you an written pronounciation in english of that word

Answer (score 0):

You are using 
var.equals()
Which will compare "a" or "ai" to the entire string. Most of the time I would imagine this is false in your case.

Use var.contains("ai") instead.

Comment: my program is about hawai language that when you enter any word of hawai language it will provide you an written pronounciation in english of that word  @Reger05

Comment: can you help me in writing my program?

Comment: @HanzalahSiddiqui Most likely no one on this site will help you write your program. This website is designed to answer specific programming questions, and be searchable, for others having the same questions in the future. If you have specific questions this website is a great place for that. If you need help writing an entire application you could find a training website like code academy(there are many others) to work on some basic skills.